# LEN error for zipping in python

Tags: zip

```
def shufflemode():
    import random
    combined = zip(question, answer)
    random.shuffle(combined)
    question[:], answer[:] = zip(*combined)
```

but then i get the error:
    TypeError: object of type 'zip' has no len()

What do I do im so confused

Comment: Did you import a type named "zip" which overrides the buildin zip function?

Comment: the only thing i imported was "random"

Comment: How do you run the code above? Can you post all your code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 2 --> 3: object of type 'zip' has no len()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31011631/python-2-3-object-of-type-zip-has-no-len)

Answer (score 1):

I wonder the same thing. According to:
[randomizing two lists and maintaining order in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343347/randomizing-two-lists-and-maintaining-order-in-python)
You should be able to do it like the OP tried, but i also get the same error. I think the ones from the link are using python 2 and not 3, could this be the problem?

Comment: This was working for me in Python 2.7 but now that I've changed to Python3 the same code encounters an error. Zip should has changed from python2 to 3.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue between Python 2 and Python 3. In Python 2 using shuffle after zip works, because zip returns a list. In Python 3: "TypeError: object of type 'zip' has no len()" because zip returns an iterator in Python 3.

Solution, use list() to convert to a list:

```
combined = list(zip(question, answer))
random.shuffle(combined)
```

The error appeared with shuffle() because shuffle() uses len().

References issue:
[The zip() function in python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31683959/the-zip-function-in-python-3)

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon this and was surprised to learn about the random.shuffle method. So I tried your example, and it worked for me in Python 2.7.5:

```
def shufflemode():
    import random
    combined = zip(question, answer)
    random.shuffle(combined)
    question[:], answer[:] = zip(*combined)

question = ["q1","q2","q3","q4","q5"]
answer = ["a1","a2","a3","a4","a5"]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    shufflemode()
    print question,answer
```

The result is two lists with the same randomized sequence of questions and answers**strong text**:

```
>>> 
['q3', 'q2', 'q5', 'q4', 'q1'] ['a3', 'a2', 'a5', 'a4', 'a1']
>>>
```