# Printing result of the zip() function in Python 3 gives "zip object at <address>"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know how to use the `zip()` function in Python 3. My question is regarding the following which I somehow feel quite peculiar:

I define two lists:

```
lis1 = [0, 1, 2, 3]
lis2 = [4, 5, 6, 7]
```

and I use the `zip()` on these in the following ways:

```
1. test1 = zip( lis1, lis2)

2. test2 = list(zip(lis1, lis2))
```

when I type `test1` at the interpreter, I get this:

```
"zip object at 0x1007a06c8"
```

So, I type `list(test1)` at the interpreter and I get the intended result, but  when I type `list(test1)` again, I get an empty list.

What I find peculiar is that no matter how many times I type `test2` at the interpreter I always get the intended result and never an empty list.

Comment: A bit shorter in Python 3: `test2 = [*zip(lis1, lis2)]`.

Comment: And `test2 = *zip(lis1, lis2),` unpacks the zip-iterator into a tuple (Python 3).

Comment: I'm reopening this because  it isn't *just* about the general issue of how iterators work in Python; it's specifically about the fact **that** `zip` produces an iterator **in 3.x**, as opposed to a list (as it did in 2.x). I haven't been able to find a better version of the question that focuses on only the latter part.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: agreed, I can't find one either, but there are several posts that (now) point to this one.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I found it: [TypeError: 'zip' object is not subscriptable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27431390). It needs a little editing to be useful as a canonical, but other stuff is probably much better closed to there, and this is closable to both (and not a good target).

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Unlike in Python 2, the `zip` function in Python 3 returns an *iterator*.  Iterators can only be exhausted (by something like making a list out of them) once.  The purpose of this is to save memory by only generating the elements of the iterator as you need them, rather than putting it all into memory at once.  If you want to reuse your zipped object, just create a list out of it as you do in your second example, and then duplicate the list by something like

```
 test2 = list(zip(lis1,lis2))
 zipped_list = test2[:]
 zipped_list_2 = list(test2)
```

Comment: One of the most important words of this great explanation is the word "once". Even testing the length of the zipped object `len(list(zipped))` will exhaust it.

Answer (score 30):

The [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function in Python 3 returns an iterator. That is the reason why when you print `test1` you get - `<zip object at 0x1007a06c8>`. [From documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) -

> Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables.

But once you do - `list(test1)` - you have exhausted the iterator. So after that anytime you do `list(test1)` would only result in empty list.

In case of `test2`, you have already created the list once, `test2` is a list, and hence it will always be that list.

Comment: isn't that behavior applicable for a generator, not an iterator?

Comment: why isn't it applicable for an iterator? Check - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776829/difference-between-pythons-generators-and-iterators - *Every generator is an iterator* . Iterators also can get exhausted, and in the same way , there can be generators that never get exhausted.