# zip object usage in python for-loop

Tags: python, for-loop, zip

Is a zip object available to use in for-loop only as the object itself?

I wish i can get some explanation why other types(like variable, list) can't be used when it is actually the same thing.

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = ['a', 'b', 'c']
​
obj1 = zip(x, y)
odj2 = list(zip(x, y))

​# working properly
for a, b in zip(x, y):
    print(a)
    print(b)     

# doesn't work and don't know why
for a, b in obj1:
    print(a)
    print(b)     

for a, b in obj2:
    print(a)
    print(b)
```

so, do i have to use zip object as itself with zip function in for-loop?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: `zip` objects are generators, so the same one can't be used more than once.

Comment: The last two cases work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The zip() function in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31683959/the-zip-function-in-python-3)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you run your provided code from the beginning, it works (except that `odj2` should be `obj2`).

The reason for your confusion is that the `zip` object is an *iterator*. It does not store elements in memory, but rather generates them on the fly, as needed. You cannot access previous elements or restart an iterator; instead, you have to construct a new one. Therefore, if you find yourself needing to iterate through such sequences more than once, you should convert them to persistent data structures, such as `lists`. For example:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = ['a', 'b', 'c']

zip_object = zip(x, y)

print('first time:')

for first, second in zip_object:
    print(first, second)

print('second time:')

for first, second in zip_object:
    print(first, second)

print('done')
```

Output:

```
first time
1 a
2 b
3 c
second time
done
```

Contrast this to the case where you use the `zip` object to create a `list`:

```
zip_object = zip(x, y)
new_list = list(zip_object)

print('first time:')

for first, second in new_list:
    print(first, second)

print('second time:')

for first, second in new_list:
    print(first, second)

print('going back to the zip object')

for first, second in zip_object:
    print(first, second)

print('done')
```

Output:

```
first time
1 a
2 b
3 c
second time
1 a
2 b
3 c
going back to the zip object
done
```

What happened is that you iterated through `obj1` somewhere, then, without creating a new `zip` object, tried to iterate through it again. Since it was already fully exhausted, there was nothing for the `for` loop to iterate over.

Comment: I appreciate your detailed explanation! Thanks! helped me out :)

Comment: I have a problem with zip and your explanation is great! Thanks