# Is zip() is a generator function in python?

Tags: python

I was wondering if zip() function is a generator function since it exhausts only after one print. 
Could anyone clarify this?

Comment: did you try googling "python zip"? [That link](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) was fourth result for me

Comment: No, the zip function is not a generator

Answer (score 3):

The `zip()` function is not a generator function, it just returns an iterators.

See here: [The zip() function in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31683959/the-zip-function-in-python-3)

You can learn more about `zip()` here: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip

Comment: It is *not* a generator, generator functions return *generators* which are iterators, but not all iterators are generators

Comment: Oops, fixed my answer