# In Python 3, hpow we can get the below output using str.format() and lists?

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, format, placeholder

User = ("Peter", James, "John)

Age = (18 , 20 , 22)

str = "{}, is a laborious student and he is {}."

Output :

1. Peter, is a laborious student and he is 18.
2. James, is a laborious student and he is 20.
3. John, is a laborious student and he is 22.

Comment: Welcome to SO! In order to post a question you should bring a minimum information as a input sample and expected output sample (if needed), what did you try and your research, in order to show some effort, as SO is not a free coding service. What did you try and research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate two tuples in parallel.

```
users = ("Peter", "James", "John")

ages = (18 , 20 , 22)

for (a, b) in zip(users, ages):
    str = "{}, is a laborious student and he is {}.".format(a, b)
    print(str)
```

[More information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31683959/the-zip-function-in-python-3)