# How to get all the minima in a tuple?

Tags: python, zip, min

I have a two variable,
a = ("0", "2", "0")
b = ("Jenny", "Christy", "Monica")
if I run the code

```
x = min(zip(a, b))
print(x)
```

my output will be ('0', 'Jenny')

If I want the output- (('0', 'Jenny'),('0','Monica))- what should I do?

Comment: sorry about the edit, did't know min() works on string too. are you using python or python3 ? zip() is different in the two see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31683959/the-zip-function-in-python-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, you want the `min` of `a`:

```
>>> [(i, j) for i, j in zip(a, b) if i == min(a)]
[('0', 'Jenny'), ('0', 'Monica')]
```

If you compare each tuple then ('0', 'Jenny') < ('0', 'Monica')

Answer (score 0):

```py
a = ("0", "2", "0")
b = ("Jenny", "Christy", "Monica")
x = list(zip(a, b))
output = []

for i in range(len(x)):
    if min(a) in x[i]:
        output.append(x[i])

print(output)
```

Actually when your code finds two minimum values in a, then it compares the minimum value of b also and it finds `'Jenny'` first letter `J` is smaller than `'Monica'` first letter `'M'`. Thats why it returns only one value

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ("0", "2", "0")
b = ("Jenny", "Christy", "Monica")
x = ()
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] == "0":
        x += (a[i],b[i])

print(x)



#Brute force way.
```

Comment: sorry to bother I'm on no question ban. Why do you think ff =['1c','2','3','4','5','6']

for i in ff:
    print(type(i),  min(ff), type(min(ff))), gives 1c as minimum

Comment: Well, I was just trying to help. I thought it would be affected because it's a string. lol