# Conditional list generation from two different lists in Python

Tags: python, list

Apologies in advance as I am quite new to this all and I'm not certain on the correct terms for everything.

I have a list of differences between two lists, called `Change`. I would like to generate a list of percentage changes `Percentage` by dividing each value in `Change` by the highest of the respective values in the lists it references (`Before` and `After`). If the wrong value is used, a percentage change is showing at -660% in some cases.

`Before` and `After` are generated from image files through PIL, but a small section of the output is below.

```
Before = [135,160,199,]
After = [146,174,176,]
Change = list(After-Before for Before,After in zip(Before,After))
PercentageA = list(Change/After*100 for After,Change in zip(After,Change))
PercentageB = list(Change/Before*100 for Before,Change in zip(Before,Change))
for x in Change:
    if x <0:
        Percentage = PercentageA
    else:
        Percentage = PercentageB
    print(Percentage)
```

This code generates:

```
In [1]:
[8.148148148148149, 8.75, -11.557788944723619]
[8.148148148148149, 8.75, -11.557788944723619]
[7.534246575342466, 8.045977011494253, -13.068181818181818]
```

However, the result should be:

```
[7.534246575342466, 8.045977011494253, -11.557788944723619]
```

My main question is; how can I generate a `Percentage` list from `Change` divided by the highest of `Before` and `After` for each value in the list?

Edit: Reduced and generalised some of the code, and deleted background. Apologies for putting too much background in.
Edit2: Apologies for misunderstanding what was asked of me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calculating something wrong - this works:

```
# list must be same lenght for zip() to work
before  = [135, 199]
after   = [146, 176]
change  = [ 11, -23]

print(f"{'before':<10} {'after':<10} {'percent':<10} {'change':<10}")

for b,a,c in zip(before, after, change):
    print (f'{b:<10} {a:<10} {c/max(b,a)*100:<10.6} {c:<10}')
```

Output:

```
before     after      percent    change    
135        146        7.53425    11
199        176        -11.5578   -23
```

Zipping 3 lists creates tuples from each list that this code iterates over. See f.e. [The zip() function in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31683959/the-zip-function-in-python-3)

Comment: Thank you very much - this has actually helped me fix it! Sorry for not knowing the correct way to layout things, but this has been very helpful.