# Python zip() two lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

I'm trying to zip two lists with the same length, but I always get the error
"zip object at 0x0000000002A81548" instead of a zipped list.

```
filename = input("Which file do you want to open?: \n")

file = open("C:/"+ filename,'r')


movielist = []
moviename = []
moviedate = []

for line in file:  
    line.strip()  
    name = re.search('name:(.*)',line)
    date = re.search('date:(.*)',line)

    if name:
        titel = name.group(1)
        moviename.append(titel)
    if date:
        datum = date.group(1)
        moviedate.append(datum)

print("Name of the list: ", moviename.pop(0))

movielist= zip(moviename,moviedate)

print(movielist)

print("Number of movies: " , len(moviename))
```

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31011631/python-2-3-object-of-type-zip-has-no-len or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048310/len-error-for-zipping-in-python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
movielist= list(zip(moviename,moviedate))
```

In Python 2 `zip` returns a list and the above is not needed. In Python 3 it returns a special lazy zip object, similar to a generator or `itertools.izip`, which you need to make concrete to use `len`. The same is true for `map`.