# Randomizing two lists and maintaining order in Python 3.4

Tags: python-3.x

I'm basically asking the exact same question as was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343347/randomizing-two-lists-and-maintaining-order-in-python), but for Python 3.4.0.

In 3.4.0, this code:

```
a = ["Spears", "Adele", "NDubz", "Nicole", "Cristina"]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

combined = zip(a, b)
random.shuffle(combined)

a[:], b[:] = zip(*combined)
```

does not work. What is the correct way to do this in 3.4.0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In python 3, `zip` returns a `zip` object (i.e. it's `itertools.izip` from python 2).

You need to force it to materialize the list:

```
combined = list(zip(a, b))
```

Comment: Thanks so much. That worked great. Could you tell me why casting to a list later in the code didn't work well? i.e.

    combined = zip(a,b)
    random.shuffle(list(combined))
    print(list(combined))

Returns an empty list

Comment: `random.shuffle` shuffles *in-place*.  Doing `list(combined)` returns a new list (and consumes `combined`), so doing `random.shuffle` on that shuffles it, then it is immediately thrown away.  Doing `list(combined)` again gives you an empty list because you consumed the `zip` object in the previous step.

Comment: Wow. That was a great answer. Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 2):

If memory was tight, you can write your own shuffle function to avoid the need to create the zipped list. The one from Python is not very complicated

```
def shuffle(self, x, random=None, int=int):
    """x, random=random.random -> shuffle list x in place; return None.

    Optional arg random is a 0-argument function returning a random
    float in [0.0, 1.0); by default, the standard random.random.

    Do not supply the 'int' argument.
    """

    randbelow = self._randbelow
    for i in reversed(range(1, len(args[0]))):
        # pick an element in x[:i+1] with which to exchange x[i]
        j = randbelow(i+1) if random is None else int(random() * (i+1))
        x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
```

Your function could be this:

```
def shuffle2(a, b):
    for i in reversed(range(1, len(a))):
        j = int(random.random() * (i+1))
        a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
        b[i], b[j] = b[j], b[i]
```

To shuffle an arbitrary number of lists in unison

```
def shuffle_many(*args):
    for i in reversed(range(1, len(args[0]))):
        j = int(random.random() * (i+1))
        for x in args: 
            x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
```

eg

```
>>> import random
>>> def shuffle_many(*args):
...     for i in reversed(range(1, len(args[0]))):
...         j = int(random.random() * (i+1))
...         for x in args: 
...             x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
... 
>>> a = ["Spears", "Adele", "NDubz", "Nicole", "Cristina"]
>>> b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> shuffle_many(a, b)
>>> a
['Adele', 'Spears', 'Nicole', 'NDubz', 'Cristina']
>>> b
[2, 1, 4, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `combined = zip(a,b)` to `combined = list(zip(a,b))`.  You need a list, not an iterator, in order to shuffle in place.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, `zip` returns an iterator rather than a list, so cast it to a list before shuffling it:

```
combined = list(zip(a, b))
```