# randomizing two lists(numpy in) and maintaining order in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have two 2d numpy lists. I want to shuffle it, but just outer side shuffle.

If i randomize order list a, I want list b to follow list a's order.

I have seen [randomizing two lists and maintaining order in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343347/randomizing-two-lists-and-maintaining-order-in-python) but this looks not work for me.

The below code is how I'm doing now.

But it's too slow for big numpy lists.

```
import numpy as np
import random    

a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12]])
b = np.array([[100,200,300,400,500], [600,700,800,900,901], [101,102,103,104,105], [501,502,503,504,505]])
r = [i for i in range(4)]
random.shuffle(r)
newa = np.empty((0, 3))
newb = np.empty((0, 5))
for rr in r:
    newa = np.append(newa, [a[rr]], axis=0)
    newb = np.append(newb, [b[rr]], axis=0)
print(newa)
print(newb)
```

Any pythonic or faster way to do this?

Thanks for answer.

Comment: `[i for i in range(4)]` -> `list(range(4))` or better yet, `np.arange(4)`

Comment: Thanks @MadPhysicist. I think my code logic fundamentally wrong.

Comment: Your logic is fine if it works. It's just somewhat inefficient. I've posted what I think is a better way.

Comment: `newa=a[r]; newb=b[r]`.  Arrays can be indexed with a while list.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj!! for good information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [randomizing two lists and maintaining order in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343347/randomizing-two-lists-and-maintaining-order-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right idea, but appending to an array is very time consuming, since it reallocates the entire buffer every time. Instead, you can just use the shuffled index:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12]])
b = np.array([[100,200,300,400,500], [600,700,800,900,901], [101,102,103,104,105], [501,502,503,504,505]])

r = np.arange(4)
np.random.shuffle(r)

newa = a[r]
newb = b[r]
```

Comment: Great!! this is much more faster than how I did. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% on performance but I think this may work better for you:

```
newa = np.copy(a)
np.random.shuffle(newa)
newb = np.copy(b)
np.random.shuffle(newb)
```

Do you need them to be in the same random order? So if element 1 moves to position 3 in `newa` should that move also occur in `newb`? That is how your code is but you don't specify in your question. If you want the same shuffle for both you need to do something like this:

```
indexes = np.arrange(len(a))
np.random.shuffle(indexes)
newa = a[indexes]
newb = b[indexes]
```

This will go faster than what you have since all of the append calls are slowing you down.

Answer (score 1):

Use the shuffle option in numpy itself, it would be much more efficient.

```
np.random.shuffle(a)
np.random.shuffle(b)

print(a)
#
[[ 4  5  6]
 [10 11 12]
 [ 7  8  9]
 [ 1  2  3]]
print(b)
#
[[600 700 800 900 901]
 [100 200 300 400 500]
 [501 502 503 504 505]
 [101 102 103 104 105]]
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I edited my questions. 
I want to randomize list a and list b to follow the list a's order.